# How do I convert a List(Of T) to an ObservableCollection(Of T) in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, collections, list

Is there a way to do this without iterating through the List and adding the items to the ObservableCollection?

Comment: See related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731626/ilistt-to-observablecollectiont

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, there is no way to directly convert the list to an observable collection. You must add each item to the collection. However, below is a shortcut to allow the framework to enumerate the values and add them for you.

```
Dim list as new List(of string)
...some stuff to fill the list...
Dim observable as new ObservableCollection(of string)(list)
```

Answer (score 19):

I'm late but I want to share this interesting piece for converting a list into a ObservableCollection if you need a loop:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    var c = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (var e in coll) c.Add(e);
    return c;
}
```

You could pass an collection to the ObservableCollection constructor:

```
List<Product> myProds = ......
ObservableCollection<Product> oc = new ObservableCollection<Product>(myProds);
```

Now you have to translate these to VB.NET :)

Comment: That's C# not VB.NET but +1 anyway for solving it for any IEnumerable (and also for being late!)

Comment: Cool joke! It is real subtle humor!!

Answer (score 3):

```
//Create an observable collection TObservable.

ObservableCollection (TObservable) =new ObservableCollection (TObservable)();

//Convert List items(OldListItems) to collection

OldListItems.ForEach(x => TObservable.Add(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

to clarify what Junior is saying (with an added example if you're using LINQ that returns an IEnumerable):

```
//Applications is an Observable Collection of Application in this example
List<Application> filteredApplications = 
      (Applications.Where( i => i.someBooleanDetail )).ToList();
Applications = new ObservableCollection<Application>( filteredApplications );
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm late, I wanna share a quick enhancement to [Junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66708/junior-mayhe)'s answer: let the developer define the converter function used to convert observable collection objects from the source collection to the destination one.

Like the following:

```
public static ObservableCollection<TDest> ToObservableCollection<TDest, TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> coll, Func<TSource, TDest> converter)
    {
        var c = new ObservableCollection<TDest>();
        foreach (var e in coll)
        {
            c.Add(converter(e));
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ObservableCollection<yourobjectname> result = new ObservableCollection<yourobjectname>(yourobjectlist);
```

Comment: please put here description of your answer.