# Create ObservableCollection from IList with grouping

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Im trying to pass a grouped observable collection to my view.

```
public void init()
{
    people = CreatePeople( 20 ).ToList(); // Creates 20 person-objects

    groupedPeople = ( from person in people
    group person by person.City into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new Group<string, Person>
    {
        Key = g.Key.ToString(),
        Items = g.ToList()
    } ).ToList();

}

private IList<Person> people;
private IList<Group<string, Person>> groupedPeople; //Contains the groupedlist that i want to "convert"

public ObservableCollection<Group<string, Person>> gp;  //This is the list I wish to pass to the view
```

In order for me to pass the list I need it in an ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<Group<string, Person>> gp;
```

Is it possible for me to "convert" my `private IList<Group<string, Person>>` to the observableCollection?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731626/ilistt-to-observablecollectiont

Comment: Thank you! Lots of info about this problem in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  gp=new ObservableCollection(groupedPeople);
```

The constructor of ObservableCollection can take an IList or an IEnumerable