# Sorting ObservableCollection by date

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have ObservableCollection AllRem

```
public sealed class GetRem
{
    public static string RemIDForNot;
    public string ReminderColor = "1";
    public int RemID { get; set; }
    public string ReminderName { get; set; }
    public string ReminderDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReminderDataTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean? ReminderDone = false; 
    ...
}
```

I need to sort my collection by ReminderDateTime. I tried using :IComparable but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried with linq - `var sortedCollection = yourCollection.OrderBy(x => x.ReminderDateTime)`?

Comment: that wont return an observable collection

Comment: Do as Romasz suggests then convert it to an observable collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731626/ilistt-to-observablecollectiont

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the collection before binding, as suggested above will work fine, if the data in the collection is not changing. If it is (and, from your data structure, I would guess so), then this becomes a good scenario for a CollectionViewSource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DS.AllRem}" x:Key="RemViewSource" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ReminderDataTime" Direction="Descending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then, bind the GridView to the CollectionViewSource

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source ={StaticResource RemViewSource}}"></GridView>
```

Comment: Yes, I need collection changing. But I do not understand how use CollectionViewSource. I have GridView with Bind to my collection ItemsSource="{x:Bind DS.AllRem, Mode=OneWay}" Where i need to use CollectionViewSource?

Comment: Basically, the structure becomes
CollectionViewSource.Source bound to ViewModel property
GridView.ItemSource bound to CollectionViewSource. I'll edit my answer to provide the full structure

Comment: I have error message  The property 'IsLiveSortingRequested' was not found in type 'CollectionViewSource' and other related whit this propertie

Comment: You need a namespace reference. Put the following in your UserControl/view declaration

xmlns:componentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

Comment: Did not help. Can the UWP does not support?

Comment: don't have any idea?

Comment: Barely. Quick google suggests  that in UWP the sorting is enabled on the CollectionView (not ViewSource) - which is, in this case the DataGrid or ItemCollection. Could you post your view code/markup?

Comment: I share my mainpage.xaml https://1drv.ms/u/s!Almt2-yL8xeklatuWRdel-TEXjLPrQ